# iPhone message attachments keep returning even after I delete them

Tags: iphone, messages, messages-in-icloud

On my iPhone 13, some iMessage conversations have nearly 100 MB of images. For one conversation, I went to "Attachments" and manually deleted every single photo, but then a few days later noticed all the ones I deleted were back, as if I never deleted them.

How do I actually delete the attachments permanently?

(iPhone 13, iOS 16.6)

Answer (score 1):

I turned off iCloud syncing of messages: i.e. **Settings** > **iCloud** > **Messages** turn to off.

After doing this, it seemed the photos still wouldn't go away, so I went to **Settings** > **Storage** > **Messages**, then under "Photos" it showed hundreds of megabytes. I manually deleted each one. Note this particular UI is quite bug-ridden and the sizes don't actually update correctly while I delete, so I had to close the Settings app (i.e. tap and hold on the screen, then explicitly "swipe away" the Settings app) then re-open a few times in order to get the correct sizes to update.

After doing this, the attachments seem to have gone away for good.